# XML pass parameter into UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Using WPF application and WPF UserControl.

I have a usercontrol that is in the main application multimple times.
There is a button in this usercontol, and on click it will show the content of a global string variable `Properties.Settings.Default.StringA;` (where "stringA" is just an example in this explenation)

For example, in this global settings i have a string parameterNameA and a parameterNameB.

I should make something like this on the main application:

UserController instance 1: 
`<local:UserControl1 stringVariable="parameterNameA" />`

UserController instance 2:
`<local:UserControl1 stringVariable="parameterNameB" />`

In the usercontroller is should get something like this:

```
public string stringVariable
{
    get 
    {
        return stringVariable; 
    }
    set 
    {
       settingThis = value; 
    }
}
```

But this one makes a string out of it.
But what i want is to make it get the correct parameter `Properties.Settings.Default.StringA;` where "StringA"  whould be the "parameterNameA" or "parameterNameB"

Really stuck in this one. Anyone have any ideas?

**===================================================**

**EDIT 1 - Revision of tht question to explain better**

I am using WPF application and WPF UserControl.

I have a UserControl that has a button in it.
Hitting this button will do: `MessageBox.Show(Properties.Settings.Default.messageA);`

So messageA is one of the global string variables.

Now im putting this userControl on the aplligation window trough the XML:

`<local:UserControl1 stringVariable="messageA" />`

But im not putting it there once, i want to put it multiple times on the application window.
But as you will understand, clicking the button it will always show messageA.

So what am i trying:
I want to add in the userControl something that would define what message to show when called `Properties.Settings.Default.messageA` but for the second instance on the application window, i dont want it to show messageA, i want it to show messageB.
So in the application window, i though of something like this:

`<local:UserControl1 stringVariable="messageA" />`

`<local:UserControl1 stringVariable="messageB" />`

So within the usercontroller, somehow it should understand that when `stringVariable="messageB"` is set, it should call `Properties.Settings.Default.messageB` and not `Properties.Settings.Default.messageA`

I hope i explained a little better now.

Comment: I've read this question about 4 times and it's still confusing. Please revise it and make it more clear what the issue is.

Comment: ok, Edited to add some more info. I really hope its more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

Why not just pass the content of your `Properties.Settings.Default.StringX` in your user control through a parameter in its constructor, keep it in as a property and use it wherever you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want here, but I'm not sure 100% because of all the fluff in your code. If I understand you correctly you want to utilize the value of the global setting instead of the name. Or, have some way to pull the value from the name of the setting...

You can still store the name of the settings variable, but you simply have to use the ConfigurationManager to return the setting based on the key (name). Make sure to include the necessary references and using statements.

```
public string StringVariable { get; set; }

public string SettingValue
{
    get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[StringVariable]; }
}
```